# My Web scraper sporadically fails due to very small difference in URLs

Tags: python-2.7, url, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I am facing this frustrating problem that has affected the speed of my data collection a lot. I have written this customized web **scraper** tailored for a specific sports website and I read the URLs from a file and then call my scraper:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import html5lib
import socket
from PassesData import *
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')

base: http://www.something.com
with open('Part2-PostIS-0430PM.txt', 'w') as f5:
    with open('URLLinks.txt') as temp:
        for url in temp:
            f5.write(getData(base+url))
            f5.write("\n")
```

Sample data in URLLinks.txt --> /something/wherein/12345

The crawler works perfectly for many hours reading URLs one by one and passing it to crawler sparsing and returning the result writing it to the text file in the outer with --> but when it reads a URL with a slight difference like:

/someting/wherein/12345   instead of /something/wherein/12345,

my crawler fails with: **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'header' referenced before assignment:**   header being the page header that I sparse from the URL like   header = soup.h1.b.text.strip() and pass it to the print function. It works perfectly for 99% of the URLs I am reading but that one URL in the middle causes the whole process to stop and then when I pass the URL to for example Google chrome it automatically fixes the missing term and fetches the correct term, for example when I pass "http://www.something.com/someting/wherein/12345" to Chrome it opens /something/wherein/12345 with no problem. And here I go and change that one URL in the URLlinks.txt and then run my crawler again which has cause huge delay in my data collection.

This has caused huge delay as I have to constantly babysit the process.

I really appreciate any solution for this.

I am using BeautifulSoup4 and socket (no use of URLLIB and other methods since they just dont work for the website I am **scraping** )

I have to again stress that my crawler works perfectly, but for the small small variations of the URL, Like having /this-is-a/link/to/12345 instead of /this-is/link/to/12345 which a browser perfectly understand but my code fails even though I have collected these URLs from the same website in the first place!!!

Please help me out. Thanks community

Comment: Could you give an example on how Chrome automatically changes "someting" to "something" for an URL? It just seems unlikely

Comment: Give chrome this: http://stackoverflow.com//questions/41051497/my-web-scraper-sporadically-due-very-small-difference-in-urls?noredirect=1#comment69311269_41051497
insted of : http://stackoverflow.com//questions/41051497/my-web-scraper-sporadically-fail-due-to-very-small-difference-in-urls?noredirect=1#comment69311269_41051497

notice the slight difference due very small --> due to very small

The DNS server automagically finds what you meant and retrieves the correct ones, but even a very small mistake is not forgivable when using the code I provided above.

Comment: It has nothing to do with DNS server. It's stackoverflow server doing the work by 301 redirect your "wrong" url to an official url for that question, you can use whatever name you want for that url as long as the question id is correct, and this is acceptable by stackoverflow. I suppose the website you are scraping do the same thing. Also you can check my answer on using `requests` to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the web scraping framework [scrapy](http://scrapy.org) which I assume will also fail with incorrect urls, but it won't stop the process, so the other requests would still work. It is also asynchronous so your requests will be handled independently and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I did something that does not solve the issue but is the next best thing. It allows me to continue scraping through while logging those URLs who were problematic so I could look them up later: The code I used is as follows:

```
with open('Part2-PostIS-Datas-7-1159AM.txt', 'w') as f5:
   log = open("LOG-P2-7-1159.txt", 'a')
   with open('Part2-Links-7.txt') as temp:
       for url in temp:
          try:
              f5.write(getData(base+url))
              f5.write("\n")
          except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
              raise
          except:
              print(url, file=log )
              pass
```

Now I can run my script and scrape the pages one by one and the 1% problematic URLs would not stop the whole process. After my data collection is over, I would have to look in my LOG files and fix the URLs and run them again.

Answer (score 0):

Really don't know what module you use for scraping, but on my side [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) works all right with the examples you give me:

```
>>> import requests
>>> response = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com//questions/41051497/my-web-scraper-sporadically-due-very-small-difference-in-urls?noredirect=1#comment69311269_41051497')
>>> response.url
u'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051497/my-web-scraper-sporadically-fails-due-to-very-small-difference-in-urls?noredirect=1'
>>> response = requests.get('http://stackoverflow.com//questions/41051497/how-wrong-can-the-name-be?noredirect=1')
>>> response.url
u'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41051497/my-web-scraper-sporadically-fails-due-to-very-small-difference-in-urls?noredirect=1'
```

As you can see no matter what kind of "wrong name" you provide, the response will perform a 301 and redirect to a correct url as per stackoverflow server asked as long as the question number is correct.